# Is this matrix-vector equation with given properties always solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a standard n-dimensional matrix-vector equation with a square matrix, $A\textbf{x} = \textbf{b}$

The matrix $A$ is not precisely known in advance, but it is known to have the following properties:

- $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} > 0$
- $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} > 0$
- $0< a_{ij} \le 1$ if $i = j$
- $a_{ij} \le 0$ if $i \ne j$

In words:

- The sum of each row or column is positive
- All elements on the main diagonal are positive and not greater than $1$
- All off-diagonal elements are zero or negative (and by the preceding statements, they must be greater than $(-1)$ )

---

Is a matrix $A$ with these properties always nonsingular, so the equation is solvable? 
If so, why? (a rigorous proof is certainly not needed, but I would like some understanding) 
If not, please provide an example $A$ that is singular.

Answer (score 2):

It is always non-singular, because it is a diagonally dominant matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix)

This can be easily seen, since the sum of every row is positive yet only the element on the diagonal is positive, hence it is bigger than the sum of the others.